# how can i print a pattern using __str__ in python?

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I need to print a rectangle using the **str** method in a class

I tried writing a function that prints the rectangle and returning it from **str** using f string:

```
def pprint(self):
    """prints a rectangle using '#'"""
    for height in range(self.__height):
        for width in range(self.__width):
            print('#', end='')
        print()

def __str__(self):
    """prints a rectangle using '#'"""
    return f"{self.pprint()}"
```

but in output I get None on the next line:

test code:

```
my_rectangle.width = 10
my_rectangle.height = 3
print(my_rectangle)
```

Output:

```
##########
##########
##########
None
```

Comment: Your `pprint` method does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pprint` method does not return anything. You should create a string and return it instead of printing to stdout.

```
def pprint(self):
    height = self.__height
    width = self.__width
    return '\n'.join('#' * width for _ in range(height))
```

Answer (score 1):

You rectangle class doesn't really need the ppprint function as you can achieve your objective by overriding repr. Something like this:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join('#' * self.width for _ in range(self.height))

print(Rectangle(5, 4))
```

**Output:**

```
####
####
####
####
####
```